# Uses for AccountContactRole vs AccountContactRelationship - pros and cons?

Tags: accountcontactrelation

I'm having trouble wording this question, so please forgive if I don't do it well:

I'm trying to evaluate the uses of `AccountContactRole` vs `AccountContactRelationship`, and I've made a list of pros and cons, but I'd like to get down to this:

**Is there a reason to go 100% for `AccountContactRelationship` and migrate all `AccountContactRole` records away?**

Pros for `AccountContactRelationship`:

- Triggers
- Process builder
- Custom fields
- Automatic population of Direct field
- Good related lists support from Account/Contact

Cons for `AccountContactRelationship`:

- Multi-select picklist
- Cannot have more than one record per Contact-Account pair (Can with `AccountContactRole`)
- Cannot rename standard fields (vote for https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lFQaQAM)
- Doesn't necessarily make the data model more complex, but does require adjusting integrations and code in the shift
- Unclear (as I read it) order of execution when triggering on this object. Also unclear how Contact triggers will fire this **IF** using the "standard" create `AccountContactRelationship` record when changing Contact.AccountId. How to pull data from old Account and old Contact?
- The "standard" create `AccountContactRelationship` feature itself is pretty murky, especially for order of execution. I can't think of a reason to use it if I can use a trigger/process, but I am curious how it works. I've not had much success lately.

Pros for `AccountContactRole`:

- Multiple roles for a Contact in a given Account
- Established

Cons for `AccountContactRole`:

- Not on Lightning Experience Roadmap - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&type=5

Comment: A con for the AccountContactRole is that it isn't on the Lighting Experience Roadmap https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&type=5 which may sway your answer if you are going down the LEX path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce document the functionality available to these two options alongside using a custom junction object here [Comparing Contacts to Multiple Accounts to Other Options](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_comparison.htm&type=5).

One consideration I'd highlight which might be important is that AccountContactRole is not visible in Lightning Experience, and is not currently on Salesforce's roadmap [Lightning Roadmap](http://lightningroadmap.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could clearly identify Pros/Cons or Features comparison of these two Objects here '[Comparing Contacts to Multiple Accounts to Others Solutions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_comparison.htm&type=5)'

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing that **Change Data Capture** is available for `AccountContactRole`, but not available for `AccountContactRelationship`.